# Moving lemma - from Liu's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Liu's book.
Let $X$ be an irreducible quasiprojective variety over an infinite field. Let $D_1 \ldots , D_n$ where $n=\dim X$ be Cartier divisors on X. Show that there exists $D_i' \equiv D_i$ (linear equivalence) such that $$\text{dim} \bigcap_{1\leq i \leq r} \operatorname{Supp} D_i' = n-r$$ for every $r \leq n$.

i am able to do this if I assume that none of the $D_i$ has empty support and that all are effective.
So my question is in two parts:

1. How can I produce a divisor with nonempty support? What if all sections of the structure sheaf is invertible?
2. In the case where all divisors are effective, the support has dimension $n-1$ ( essentially by Krull) - how do we extend this to the general case?

Comment: Dear Heidar, Do you know about ample and very ample divisors?  (I'm not familiar with Liu's book, so I don't know what tools he is giving you to use.)  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt: I do know about ample and very ample divisors - But I fail to see how I could apply it here.  Any further hint? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

If $D$ is a divisor, let $H$ be a very ample divisor for which $D + H$ is also very ample.  (For quasi-projective varities, such $H$ always exists.)

Then write $D = (D + H) - H$.  Now we can vary $D+H$ and $H$ as much as we like,
so that they meet properly.

(Remember the *very ample* just means *hyperplane sections with respect to some projective embedding*, and we can always move a hyperplane (in this case the hyperplane whose intersectino with $X$ equals $D+H$) so that it meets any given subvariety (in this case $H$) properly.)

Now continue by induction on $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a brief check: The way we are ensuring that D has non-empty support is through varying the hyperplane divisor? Another ignorant question: Why does this imply non-empty support? I think I follow the other things fine.

Comment: @HeidarSvan: Dear Heidar, I'm not sure I understand your question.  $D+H$ is a very ample divisor, the intersection of $X$ with a hyperplane under some projective embedding.  Certainly we can choose the hyperplane so that this intersection is non-empty.   But I think your concern about non-empty support is a bit misplaced (e.g. in the case that $X$ is actually projective, the intersection with a hyperplane will never be non-empty).  The problem is that *a priori* a divisor may not move at all; that is why we add a very ample divisor to it in the first place. Regards,

Comment: Let me try to be more precise: Let us consider the case where $n=1$ . Then my worry is that the support of D would be empty. We need to find a linearly equivalent divisor with non-empty support. In the $n=1$ case, how do we find such a linearly equivalent divisor?

Comment: @Heidear: Dear Heidar, The divisor $D$ has empty support precisely if it vanishes.  To find a linearly equivalent divisor with non-empty support, just consider an projective embedding $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^N$, let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two distinct hyperplane sections of $X$, and consider $D_1 - D_2$.  (This is just my above argument with $H$ being the very ample divisor corresponding to the given projective embedding, with $D$ taken to be zero.)  As I wrote, this is not the real point of the problem.  The more substantial part is to show that you can move divisors enough so that ...

Comment: ... the intersections are proper (so that the dimension is $n - r$ and not something bigger).  I would spend more time thinking about that, rather than focusing on the somewhat tangential point of dealing with case of the zero divisor.  Regards,

Comment: Dear MattE: The reason that I am asking is that the previous problem of the book showed that for a quasiprojective variety X over a field k, we can for a given finite set of points and a divisor D on X find a linearly equivalent divisor missing these points. So I thought that of we could find a divisor with nonempty support missing the associated points, the intersection of D and X will intersect properly. Is this idea incorrect? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Since intersect properly is the same as missing these points, right?